# Error thrown by LoadRunner.js as part of webpack: callback was already called or code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'

Tags: node.js, linux, electron

Software:Electron for Linux - https://www.electronjs.org/

`Error: callback(): The callback was already called. at context.callback (C:\Users\larry.jones\professional\projects\the-elmish-book\fable-getting-started\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:106:10)`

or

`opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ], library: 'digital envelope routines', reason: 'unsupported', code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'`

So i had this issue, with Electron where LoadRunner.js was giving "callback was already called".
And it was spinning me around for some time.
Finally i had a brake in the case.
The main article that made headway was https://github.com/Zaid-Ajaj/fable-getting-started/issues/32, he managed to brake down the issue.

To sum it up resolution was that in your "`package.json`" add line `export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`

Example:

```
"main": "main.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
"start": "export SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng build"
```

From what i can see this issue is for old setup, its connected with NodeJs 17.